# How to debug high CPU usage?

Tags: c#-3.0

What tools to use to find out what cause a high CPU usage in .net application?

WPF / C# 3.0 / .net 3.5

Answer (score 10):

Apply a profiler to understand where the CPU is being used: what parts of your code are "hot". You can then review the design of those parts of the code.

Note, the high CPU usage could be completely reasonable.

Comment: +1. Agreed that high CPU is not inherently a bad thing, unless perhaps when the whole machine bogs down or comes to a crawl.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to find out where your application spends most of the CPU time - I suggest you run a performance profiler such as:

1. [JetBrains DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
2. [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)

And see where you spend most of the time.
If you want to profile specific bottlenecks you can try using Stopwatch. I've written the [details at my blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2009/11/04/poor-developer-s-performance-profiler.aspx).

Comment: not sure if using `Stopwatch` will help to understand what parts of code are causing high CPU usage.

Comment: @MainMa Using stopWatch is only good if you already has some suspects and want to verify it. Otherwise use a profiler

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, you need a profiler. Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate Edition has a built-in profiler. I haven't used it but it should be useful as an alternative to DotTrace or ANTS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

VS2013 already comes with a very good build-in profiler